# $(id).submit() not triggering submission of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that needs to do two things when the user clicks the submission button. The first is send an e-mail to me, and the second is send the user to PayPal. I have set it up so it first makes an Ajax call to another page, and that page sends the e-mail. Once that page returns a success, it calls a function to trigger the submission of the form.

I've put in the form with a standard button, rather than a submission button, and an onclick even to detect when it's clicked. Everything works great up until I try to submit the form after the Ajax call, at which point the form isn't submitted. Here's my javascript:

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {

    var err = false;
    $('input, textarea', '#booking-form').each(function(index, element) {
        if($(this).is('[required]') && $(this).val() < 2) {
            alert('Please enter your ' + $(this).prop('placeholder').toLowerCase() + ' before continuing.');
            $(this).focus();
            err = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(err) {
        return false;
    }

    if($('#date').val() == 0) {
        alert('You must choose a date before booking');
        return false;
    }

    ShowLoadingScreen();

    var data = {
        'name': $('#name').val(),
        'address': $('#address').val(),
        'tel': $('#tel').val(),
        'email': $('#email').val(),
        'course': $('#course').find('option:selected').text(),
        'location': $('#location').find('option:selected').text(),
        'date': $('#date').find('option:selected').text()
    };
    AjaxHandler('book-course.php', data, "POST", true);
    //AjaxHandler sends the data off to book-courses.php, which then returns a call to BookingSuccess(). 
    //This is working fine as evidenced by the console.log line showing in the console.

});


function BookingSuccess() {

    $('#booking-form').submit();
    console.log('Booking success called...');

}
```

AjaxHandler is a custom function that calls the page, and then handles certain responses, including calling functions. BookingSuccess is being called, as Booking success called... is being output in the console. The form however just isn't being submitted.

I have created a [jsFiddle of the issues here](http://jsfiddle.net/styphon/sRp5m/2/).

---

**What I've tried**

So far I've tried the following:

- Skipping around the Ajax - no effect
- Submitting the form directly using a button, ignoring the need for Ajax - the form works fine.
- Deleted all HTML except for the form - no effect
- Tried submitting the form at the top of the `#submit-btn` click event - no effect
- Place a return true function inside the `$('#booking-form').submit()` - no effect
- Using the longer version of jQuery's trigger `$('#booking-form').trigger('submit')` - no effect.
- Putting a `console.log` event in the forms `onsubmit=""` to see if the form is being triggered - Works on the fiddle, but not the website.

I'm at a loss as to why this form will not submit. Nothing should be stopping it. We're getting to and passing that line. I have placed a break in FireBug and stepped in, and we get to that function fine. It just doesn't do its job.

How can I get this form to submit properly as it should?

Comment: What's your console output?

Comment: Works for me (when you place `courses` at the top so it's within scope). Also, binding to a button click isn't the best method; what if the user presses enter?

Comment: When You call BookingSuccess()? It's not shown in Your code

Comment: @BradChristi I take it you mean the fiddle? I didn't realise that variables had to be at the top to be in scope. It works fine at the bottom in normal javascript.

Comment: @VaheShadunts It's called by AjaxHandler as a result of the ajax call, as I explained above. It's too big a function to include here.

Comment: @Desertlvy The console shows Booking success called, plus some others from the AjaxHandler. No errors.

Comment: You should have put `AjaxHandler()`'s code here instead of these.

Comment: @MahanGM `AjaxHandler()` is not the issue. It works perfectly fine, it's used in many situations by our company for various things. I have taken it completely out of the loop, calling BookingSuccess directly in its place, and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further inspection (and some dead ends and red herrings in the chat), it looks like the page has two elements with the same ID. Change one or the other, and you're golden.